# How to identity recordtype?

Tags: administration

In our organization we have created several record types for case object, identifying particular record type of case record belongs to is getting very difficult (have to check the profile etc).. Is their any way to easily identify the record type of a case record or in general for any object record.

Comment: Identify the Record Type through the UI when looking at a record or through Apex and SOQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the Record Type field to the page layout, and make it read-only if you don't want users changing it. You'll need to add this field to each page layout it should be visible on.

Comment: I think the question is about how to know what record types each profile has access without  going to profile page ?

Comment: "Identify the type of a case record..." This bit in English implies that they want to see the record type of the case. The author apparently was checking the record type by visually comparing the page layout being used.

Answer (score 0):

We have a practice of creating a formula field called "record type name" on every object that uses record types.

This lets you query by name instead of hard-coding ids or doing relationship queries, and also helps in certain situations where the relationship isn't available.

It doesn't give you the selectivity of record type, but saves a lot of other work.

Comment: Does your formula field use the Name or the DeveloperName? The DeveloperName field is the unique name and should be preferred.

Comment: We used the regular name.  But I agree with you that developer would be smarter.  Not sure if that used to be an option when we started this.